# Prevent opening the first form again c#

Tags: c#, forms, button

When i run my desktop app form1 is opened first and when a row of the data grid view1 is clicked an instance of form2 is opened.form2 has several textboxes and when I fill them and click the button those values are to be shown in data grid view 2 of form1!

following gives the code of form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    string dbconnection;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dbconnection = @" Data Source = D:\SQLite\SQLiteStudio\DB1.db ; version=3 ";

    }
    private static Form1 f1;

    public static Form1 getInstance(){
        if (f1 == null)
        {
            f1 = new Form1();
        }
        else
            f1.BringToFront();
            return f1;

    }

    private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                {
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(dbconnection))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    string sql = "select MESSAGE_ID from Message";
                    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
                    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    //dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1;
                   // dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Message ID";
                    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                    ds.Load(reader);
                   dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception m)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(m.Message);
            }

        }
    }



    }

    public void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();

        f2.IDtext.Text = row.Cells["MESSAGE_ID"].Value.ToString();
        f2.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        }    
}
    }
```

following is the code of form2

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     /*   if (f1 == null)
        {
            f1 = new Form1();
        } */
        Form1 f1x = Form1.getInstance();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        f1x.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
         dt1.Columns.Add("MessageID", typeof(string));
         dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
          dt1.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(string));


        DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["MessageID"] = IDtext.Text; ;
        dr["Name"] = nameText.Text;
        dr["Number"] = numberText.Text;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
        f1x.Show();   
    }
}
```

I wrote a method named getinstance() in form1 to achieve this yet a new window gets opened.
I want the values to appear in the form1 which I loaded initially but the data is shown in a new instance of form1. How can I show the data in the initial form1 that I loaded

Comment: You never set `f1` in `Form1` before calling `Form1.getInstance` so you explicitly create a new `Form1`. Why don't you simply pass a reference to the existing `Form1` to 'Form2` when you create it? Alternatively, you could add an event to `Form2` that you handle in `Form1`.

Comment: @oerkelens can u give a code snippet for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code change th construcor and getinstance to:

```
private static Form1 f1;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    f1 = this;
    dbconnection = @" Data Source = D:\SQLite\SQLiteStudio\DB1.db ; version=3 ";

}

public static Form1 getInstance(){
        f1.BringToFront();
        return f1;
}
```

Note: this is not the most elegant of code: you could ommit the static stuff and simply inject the instance of Form1 into the constructor of Form2 like this:

```
   ...
   Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
   ...
```

and in Form 2:

```
   Form1 f1x;

   Public Form2(Form1 parentForm)
   {
       InitializeComponents;
       f1x = form
   }
```

and ommit the

```
 Form1 f1x = Form1.getInstance();
```